# Como exibir log do tomcat na tela

Tags: java, jsf-2.2, tomcat

estou criando uma funcionalidade usando jsf com primefaces, para exibir o log da aplicação (tomcat), na tela (view xhtml), porem não encontrei nenhum plugin ou append para fazer isso, e antes de começar a desenvolver tudo na mão gostaria de saber se ja existe algo no mercado.

ou se alguém já desenvolveu algo parecido, que possa ajudar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente, não existe nenhuma forma "pronta" de fazer isso.

O que pode ser feito é:

1. Logar as informações em um arquivo
2. Programar a view para que a cada X tempo, ela leia o arquivo (ou peça para que o back-end leia e devolva as informações).

Comment: tinha pensado nisso caso não encontrasse algo pronto, obrigado pela ajuda Igor.